# AttributeError at /accounts/activate/Ng/5ho-db922c523f2c7f1a7f51/ 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

I am implementating custom registration flow in which a user gets a verification email upon registration and thence clicks on the confirmation link to activate account. However, clicking the link gives this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/activate/Ng/5ho-db922c523f2c7f1a7f51/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/webapps/django/Bloom/Bloom/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/webapps/django/Bloom/Bloom/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/webapps/django/Bloom/Bloom/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/webapps/django/Bloom/accounts/views.py", line 118, in activate
    user = User.objects.get(id=uid)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

I am using `Django 3.0.7` and the function I think orchestrated this error is:

```
def client_sign_up(request):

    msg = 'Input your credentials'

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClientSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            # user can't login until link confirmed
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Please Activate Your Account'
            # load a template like get_template() 
            # and calls its render() method immediately.
            message = render_to_string('accounts/activation_request.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            # method will generate a hash value with user related data
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            return redirect("accounts:activation_sent")
        else:
            msg = 'Form is not valid'    
    else:
        form = ClientSignUpForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "msg": msg,
        "section": "signup"
    }
    return render(request, "accounts/register.html", context)
```

And, particularly:

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(id=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError):
        user = None
    # checking if the user exists, if the token is valid.
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        # if valid set active true 
        user.is_active = True
        # set signup_confirmation true
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        return redirect('accounts:client_signin')
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/activation_invalid.html')
```

I am also using a custom user model and my imports look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.conf import settings
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ClientLoginForm, ClientSignUpForm
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .tokens import account_activation_token

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

I have tried changing the `user = User.objects.get(id=uid)` in line 118, the source of the error according to the error message, to `user=User.objects.get(ok=uid)` and googling, but none helped. I need you to help fix it please.

Comment: Please post your model. Is id a uuid field? If you are using the django user model, id should be an integer, not a uuid.

Comment: @Michael Hawkins, I have corrected the mistake, and everything is working fine now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, looking at my imports again, I discovered that:

```
from django.conf import settings
.
.
.
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

gives a string.

Changing it to:

```
from .models import User
```

fixed it.

Thanks everyone.